# How can I logout from Expo Apple developper account?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building my app with `expo build:ios` for the second time (so the CLI is not asking for my Apple Developper credentials again). However, I want to change this account for another one.

Is it possible ?

The CLI give me : 
`[15:43:03] Using existing credentials for this build`

When I tried : `expo logout` it logged me out from my Expo Account (not my Apple Developper one).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expo build:ios -c` will build and remove existing credentials from Expo servers.